DBT schema problems using external
The problem I'm having
Hello! I don't have much experience with dbt. I am trying to create a table via an external table in Databricks. I have it defined in raw/source.yaml as follows:
- name: table_1
  freshness:
    warn_after: {count: 12, period: hour}
    error_after: {count: 24, period: hour}
  external:
    location: "{{'s3://datahub-' + env_var('environment') + '-raw/table_1/'}}"
    using: csv
    infer_schema: true
    partitions:
      - name: timestamp
        data_type: integer
  columns:
    - name: col_1
      data_type: string
    - name: col_2
      data_type: string
    - name: col_n
      data_type: string

The context of why I'm trying to do this
My problem is that my CSV contains more columns than I have defined in my YAML, and when I create the table using:
dbt run-operation stage_external_sources --args "{select: raw.table_1}" --vars "ext_full_refresh: true"

Data from columns that I don't want are populating the columns that I do want.
Could you please help me fix this issue? I have tried to force schema with infer_schema(I dont know if this applies only to data_type) and I dont know to force to adapt my data to my schema defined in the yaml
ANSWER:
Looks like your Column order must match for CSVs.

Specify ALL column names + datatypes.
Column order must match for CSVs, column names must match for other formats.
Some databases support schema inference.

reference:
https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-external-tables?tab=readme-ov-file#spec

I'd guess that col_1, col_2 and col_n aren't the first three columns in your csv, but without the input data, it's impossible to tell. Please [edit] your question and add the contents of your CSV file to turn this into a [MCVE].

Currently I found the solution in dbt github. I edit my question with the correct answer. Thanks you anyway for your interest

Glad you were able to work it out. Could you please post the solution as an answer and mark it as accepted ? Self-answering questions is perfectly fine, and that way, it won't appear in the list of unanswered questions.

ANSWER:
Looks like your Column order must match for CSVs.
Specify ALL column names + datatypes.
Column order must match for CSVs, column names must match for other formats.
Some databases support schema inference.
reference: https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-external-tables?tab=readme-ov-file#spec
